# two dimensional array with links and linkweights in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, junit, nodes

I am working on a page ranking case study where the input is firstly the number of nodes, followed by the links for each page i to page j. The entire input has to be split according to lines and spaces (since the input is one big string consisting of multiple lines with integers). The tests I want to implement are: getNodeSize which simply returns the node, hasLink(integer i, integer j) of boolean whether or not (resp., true or false) there is a link from node i to node j (counting from 0 to nodes-1 ), and a method linkWeight(integer i, integer j) that returns the number of links between integer i and j. (after that there are some other methods but I will figure those out later)
My code so far is:

```
public class WebGraph {
        static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        static int nodes = s.nextInt();
        double wg [][]= new double [nodes][nodes];
        static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        static int[][] counts = new int[nodes][nodes];    
        static int[] outDegree = new int[nodes];

public static WebGraph initFromScanner(Scanner s) {  

    do{
        for(int i = 0; i<nodes-1; i++){
    }
        String[] strArray = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        }       
    }while(s.hasNext());
    return null;
}

public Object getNodeSize() {
    nodes = s.nextInt();
    return nodes;
}
public boolean hasLink(int i, int j) {
    for (int h = 0; h<wg[i].length; h++) {
        if(h==j){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void linkWeight(int a, int b) {
    while (s.hasNext())  {
        int i = s.nextInt(); 
        int j = s.nextInt(); 
        outDegree[i]++; 
        counts[i][j]++; 
}
}
public List<Integer> successorsSortedList(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public int[][] asMatrix() {

    return null;
}
public Set<Integer> successorsSortedSet(int i) {

    return null;
}
}
```

for the testcase:

```
public class I5Exc4aTest {
    WebGraph wg;
    /**
     * This will be invoked before each testcase.
     * Ensure to copy/paste the content of file
     * 'ext/web1.txt' to the Eclipse console.
     * In L6, we will teach you how to automate that!
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please copy/paste the content of "
                + "file 'ext/web1.txt' to this console. "
                + "Then, press ENTER.");
        wg = WebGraph.initFromScanner(s);
    }

@Test
public void testGetNodeSize() {
    assertEquals(50, wg.getNodeSize());
}
@Test
public void testHasLink1() {
    assertFalse(wg.hasLink(0, 0));
}
@Test
public void testHasLink2() {
    assertTrue(wg.hasLink(0, 7));
}
@Test
public void testLinkWeight1() {
    assertEquals(1, wg.linkWeight(0, 7));
}
@Test
public void testLinkWeight2() {
    assertEquals(1, wg.linkWeight(0, 34));
}
@Test
public void testLinkWeight3() {
    assertEquals(2, wg.linkWeight(1, 22));
}
@Test
public void testSuccessorsSortedList() {
    List<Integer> a = wg.successorsSortedList(1);
    List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(new Integer(14),
            new Integer(22), new Integer(22), new Integer(45));
    assertTrue("Expected 'a' and 'expected' to be equal."+
            "\n 'a' = "+a+
            "\n 'expected' = "+expected,
            expected.equals(a));
}
@Test
public void testSuccessorsSortedSet() {
    Set<Integer> a = wg.successorsSortedSet(1);
    Set<Integer> expected = new java.util.TreeSet<Integer>(
            Arrays.asList(new Integer(14), new Integer(22), new Integer(45)));
    assertTrue("Expected 'a' and 'expected' to be equal."+
            "\n 'a' = "+a+
            "\n 'expected' = "+expected,
            expected.equals(a));
}
@Test
public void testAsMatrix1() {
    int[][] copy= wg.asMatrix();
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, copy[0]);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, copy[1]);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0}, copy[2]);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0}, copy[3]);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, copy[4]);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0}, copy[5]);
}
}
```

Any help on any of the methods would be greatly appreciated since now none of my test cases work.

EDIT:
I am sorry for the unclear parts, this is the complete assignment:

"1.Provide a class WebGraph with an attribute w, and a method initFromScanner(Scanner s) that initializes itself by reading from the command line, based on the following format:

(a) The first input value is of type integer and represents the number of
nodes in the graph. In the following, we call the value of that integer N,

(b) The next N lines always start by an integer i representing a source
node's ID and then a (potentially empty) sequence of integers j that
denote links from node i to node j.

An example corresponding to this structure is listed below. This
example encompasses 5 nodes, where there a link from node 0 to
node 1, a link from node 0 to node 2, but no link from node 0 to
itself nor to nodes 3 or 4.

5

0 1 2

1 1 2 3

2 2 2 2 3 1

3

4 3 0 0

2. Provide a method getNodeSize that returns the value of N,
3. Provide a method hasLink(integer i, integer j) of type boolean
   that returns whether or not (resp., true or false) there is a link from
   node i to node j (counting from 0 to N-1 ),
4. Provide a method linkWeight(integer i, integer j) of type integer
   that returns the number of links from node i to node j (counting from 0
   to N-1 ),
5. Provide a method successorsSortedSet(integer i) of type Set
   which represents the set of successor nodes according to the outgoing links
   of node i, ordered by node ID.
6. Provide a method successorsSortedList(integer i) of type List
   which represents a sequence of successor nodes according to the outgoing
   links of node i, ordered by node ID.
7. Provide a method asMatrix() of type integer[][] that returns the ma-
   trix representation described above. Ensure that you do not allow updates to the internal data of your object!"

Comment: static method initFromScanner does not modify any of the static variables of its class and it returns null. So all it does is to read some data into the bit bucket. Is this according to plan?

Comment: As initFromScanner returns null it is clear that none of the tests relying on an object of class WebGraph can work.

Comment: Method hasLink uses a loop to check whether parameter j is one of the values from 0 to wg[i].length-1. This can be checked simply by comparing j with 0 and the other value. - Probably you mean something else?

Comment: A method getNodeSize looks like a "getter". As it reads and sets an instance variable it is actually a "getter" and a "setter", which will confuse all users of this class and introduce bugs.

Comment: Method linkWeight(int a, int b) has two parameters, neither of which is used. You write that it should return something (and the tests try to match its return value) but, alas, it is a void method.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear parts, this is the complete assignment:

Comment: Thanks for adding the text of the assignment. But, considering the comments I wrote: what do you expect?

Comment: firstly, considering the linkWeight, java urged me to change the names of int a and int b so it wouldn't allow me to use them. Considering the initFromScanner it was somewhat the same issue where the return type can only be void or it returns null, otherwise java wouldn't accept it. Regarding the getNodeSize, this is indeed not a smart move. hasLink should return true if link j is in array[i] but I couldn't quite get the code right